# Is it possible to re-route a Firewire DV Input as a webcam to use it in Google+ Hangouts?

Tags: video, streaming, webcam, firewire, google

I'm trying to use a Firewire DV input in a Google+ Hangout in order to do Hangouts on Air. Currently, it appears that Hangouts does not support DV inputs, which makes things difficult (essentially, the DV input goes to a tape deck which is passing through final video from "upstream" in our studio).

Are there any good solutions out there that could perhaps "route through" the DV camera as a webcam so that it shows up in Hangouts? I'm aware there's bound to be some latency/quality issues (the former is less of a problem as we can work around it), but the solution we've already tried (I'll update if I get the name of the program) clipped our video badly. I've run across this program [CamCamX](http://b-l-a-c-k-o-p.com/CamCamX.html) which seems like it could do the job - does anyone have experience with it or other similar programs for Mac?

Comment: where is the Apple product in all this?

Comment: Haha fair point, this is operation is running on a MacBook Pro because of the FireWire interoperability, since that's by far the most feasible way to use FireWire in a cheap and mobile setup, which is what we need. So I'm asking more specifically about Mac software that could solve my problem.